# Coin experiment repeated 100 times

Tags: probability, statistics

I toss a coin for N=30 times in a row and i repeat this experiment 100 times.
I obtain this graph:

[image]

If i repeat this experiment the same 100 times, but with N=40, what i expect is that this diagram will be more tighter. Am i correct ?

Furthermore do you know a procedure to get a Probability Density Function from a graph like this ?

Answer (score 1):

You'd expect your number of heads to be higher if the tossed the coin more times, so if you just add the extra 10 onto the end of the $x$-axis, your curve will shift across to around $20$. In addition, it's also likely that your curve's height will increase, and indeed, it should widen throughout as you'll be getting the higher scores more.

Comment: So it will become : (1) shifted (2) higher (3) larger . 
Do you know a procedure to trasform this graph into a pdf ?

Comment: Why would the graph get higher? I think with $N=30$ the expected value at the peak at $15$ is about $14.4$ while with $N=40$ the expected peak at $20$ is about $12.5$.  Since the total number of observations remains at $100$, a more spread out graph is likely to have a lower peak

Comment: What is the formula to calculate the expected value at the peak ?